# ng-change not working, AngularJS 1.x

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

`AngularJS 1.59`

When I edit the `quantity` input field the `ng-change` event doesn't fire.

In Chrome Dev Tools I place a breakpoint on `$scope.updateToggle` and it is never hit.

I've looked at other posts on SO but cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

HTML:

```
@section scripts {
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Binding/ViewModels/CartViewModel.js")"
      type="text/javascript"></script> }    
<br />
<span class="cart-header">Shopping Cart</span>

<div data-ng-app="appCart">
  <div ng-controller="CartViewModel">
    <div class="spinner-config" ng-show="viewModelHelper.isLoading">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
    <span style="padding-left:600px"></span>
    <span class="cart-price-header">Price</span>
    <span class="cart-quantity-header">Quantity</span>
    <hr align="left" width="850px" class="cart-hr">
    <div ng-repeat="item in cartItems | orderBy:'Title'">
      <img class="cart-img" src="{{item.Image}}">
      <span class="cart-title">{{item.Title}}</span>
      <span class="cart-price">{{item.Price | currency:"$"}}</span>

     <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="cart-quantity"
         name="quantity" ng-model="item.Quantity" ng-change="updateToggle()">

      <div style="height:2px"></div>
      <button class="btn primary delete-btn"
              ng-click="deleteItem(item.CartItemId)">Delete</button>

      <div ng-show={{quantityChanged}}>
        <button class="btn primary update-btn"
                ng-click="updateItem(item.CartItemId)">Update</button>
      </div>

      <br />
      <div style="height:25px"></div>
      <hr align="left" width="850px" class="cart-hr">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
appCartModule.controller("CartViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $timeout, viewModelHelper) {
  $scope.quantityChanged = false;

  $scope.updateToggle = function () {
    $scope.quantityChanged = true; }

  $scope.updateItem = function (cartItemID) {
    console.log("Update Item " + cartItemID);
  }

});
```

Comment: Is there any errors? Can you try to console log?

Comment: No errors in console log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
<div ng-show={{quantityChanged}}>
```

You can't assign it in `curly brackets`, instead use `double quotes`

Like this

```
<div ng-show="quantityChanged">
```

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<span class="cart-header">Shopping Cart</span>

<div >
 <div >
  <div class="spinner-config" ng-show="viewModelHelper.isLoading">
   <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
  <span style="padding-left:600px"></span>
  <span class="cart-price-header">Price</span>
  <span class="cart-quantity-header">Quantity</span>
  <hr align="left" width="850px" class="cart-hr">
  <div ng-repeat="item in cartItems | orderBy:'Title'">
   <img class="cart-img" src="{{item.Image}}">
   <span class="cart-title">{{item.Title}}</span>
   <span class="cart-price">{{item.Price | currency:"$"}}</span>

   <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="cart-quantity"
     name="quantity" ng-model="item.Quantity" ng-change="updateToggle()">

   <div style="height:2px"></div>
   <button class="btn primary delete-btn"
       ng-click="deleteItem(item.CartItemId)">Delete</button>

   <div ng-show="quantityChanged">
    <button class="btn primary update-btn"
        ng-click="updateItem(item.CartItemId)">Update</button>
   </div>

   <br />
   <div style="height:25px"></div>
   <hr align="left" width="850px" class="cart-hr">
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
</div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.carname = "Volvo";
  $scope.quantityChanged = false;
  $scope.cartItems = [{
    Title: 'a',
    Price: '20'
  }];


 $scope.updateToggle = function () {
  $scope.quantityChanged = true; }

 $scope.updateItem = function (cartItemID) {
  console.log("Update Item " + cartItemID);
 }

});
</script>

<p>The property "carname" was made in the controller, and can be referred to in the view by using the {{ }} brackets.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, with the curly braces if I set '$scope.quantityChanged' to 'true' in the js file the 'Update' button displays.  The problem is that the 'updateToggle' function is never called.  When I use double quotes it sets '$scope.quantityChanged' to true, the 'Update' button displays but the 'breakpoint' on 'updateToggle' is never hit.  Any idea why the breakpoint is not hit, it makes it difficult to troubleshoot?

Comment: When I set a `breakpoint` on a command in the `updateToggle` function it does get hit. Sudhir's suggestion to use `ng-keyup` works also and works with the `{{ }}`.  But I think you're right and the more proper usage is `""`.

Answer (score 1):

First in your html code change this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="cart-quantity"
         name="quantity" ng-model="item.Quantity" ng-keyup="updateToggle(item.Quantity)">
```

And in controller do like this :

```
$scope.updateToggle = function (quantity) 
{
   if(quantity)
   {    
      $scope.quantityChanged = true; 
   }
}
```

Comment: This works but the real problem was the `{{ }}` instead of `""` on the ng-show.  Saurabh's answer was more correct.